# UItabelView doesn't display my content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Any help will be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for quite a while. i added content to my UITableView and reload the data nothing happens and I cant quite figure out whats going on with my parkinglistviewcontroller. Well here's my code that I'm using.

.m File

```
@implementation ParkingListViewController
@synthesize objCustomCell;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arrParkingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    arrAnnotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self locate];
    [parkingMap setRegion:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(parkingMap.userLocation.coordinate, 5, 5) animated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [locationManager release];
    [tblParkingList release];
    [parkingMap release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [tblParkingList release];
    tblParkingList = nil;
    [parkingMap release];
    parkingMap = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}


#pragma mark - Tableview Methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arrParkingList.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ParkingCustomCell *cell = (ParkingCustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ParkingCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.objCustomCell;
        self.objCustomCell = nil;
    }

    ClsParking *objTmpParking = [arrParkingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.lblTitle.text = objTmpParking.strLocation;
    cell.imgUserImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imgUserImage.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
    [cell.imgUserImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:objTmpParking.strImageUrl] placeholderImage:nil];
    return  cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 68;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ClsParking *objParking = [arrParkingList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    float fltLatitude = [objParking.strLatitude floatValue];
    float fltLongitude = [objParking.strLongitude floatValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D pLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(fltLatitude, fltLongitude);

    [self setMapCenter:pLocation];

}

- (IBAction)btnAddTapped:(id)sender
{
    ParkingNotificationViewController *objParkingNotificationViewController =[[ParkingNotificationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParkingNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:objParkingNotificationViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    [objParkingNotificationViewController release];
}

- (IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}



@end
```

.h file

```
@class ParkingCustomCell;
@interface ParkingListViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate,MKMapViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *tblParkingList;
    NSMutableArray *arrParkingList;
    AppDelegate *appDelegate;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    IBOutlet MKMapView *parkingMap;
    NSMutableArray *arrAnnotations;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet ParkingCustomCell *objCustomCell;

- (IBAction)btnAddTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnBackTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here's my parkingcustomcell class

```
@implementation ParkingCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_lblTitle release];
    [_imgUserImage release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Put logs in the table data source methods. Are those methods being called? Also, it appears that you never add anything to arrParkingList, so why would you expect to see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewdidload method add the following :

```
self. tblParkingList.delegate = self;
self. tblParkingList.delegate = self;
```

Also @synthesize tblParkingList;

After that you have initialised  an array arrParkingList for populating the table.Add content to it because it is empty.

Comment: In the end of viewDidLoad write this.

Comment: Seems like your datasource and delegate is not set.

Comment: Also you have IBOutlet UITableView *tblParkingList in your .h so make sure it is connected in IB

Comment: I added this and still no content is showing.

Comment: is your array empty?Check out this using NSlog(@"count :%d",[arrParkingList count])

Answer (score 1):

In addition to AdamG's comment, I see you have allocated space for `arrParkingList` array, but I can't see where you add values to it/initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you set the class as the delegate for the tableview and the datasource delegate for the tableview.  You can do this in the storyboarding by control dragging from the tableView to the icon on the left hand side of the bar, or by adding the following lines of code to your app..

```
 self.tableView.delegate = self;
 self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Also make sure that your tableView is declared as an outlet in your .h file.  I am assuming you dragged it as an outlet called "tableView" in the above example.

Hope that helps!

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: Place it in "viewDidLoad"